# Online configuration tool for iptables?

Tags: iptables

Are there any online tools that can spit-out a customised config for `iptables`? I'm specifically looking for something that has options to include/exclude rules to guard against common attacks.

Answer (score 6):

you can use:

http://easyfwgen.morizot.net/gen/

http://www.mista.nu/iptables/

But these rule generators are not much sophisticated. They just create very basic rulesm not advanced.
So better use an PHP based front end to create advanced level of iptables rules, here is one

http://phpfwgen.sourceforge.net/

Comment: phpfwgen looks interesting, but it seems to want to install the config locally. I need something I can use to generate config files and then download them.